# How to create 16 bit bmp image?

Tags: c#, bmp

I try to create a 16 bit bmp / jpg file using following code:

```
    public static void CreateBitmap_Rgb48(int width, int height, double dpiX, double dpiY, string fn)
    {
        int bytesperpixel = 6; // BytesPerChannel = 2,ChannelCount = 3 (bgr)
        int channelCount = 3;
        int stride = width * bytesperpixel;
        byte[] imgdata = new byte[width * height * bytesperpixel];

        int rectDim = 40;
        ushort[] intPixelData = new ushort[width * height * channelCount];
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < width * channelCount; col += channelCount)
            {
                if (((col / channelCount / rectDim) % 2) != ((row / rectDim) % 2))
                {
                    intPixelData[row * width * channelCount + col + 0] = 0x0000;
                    intPixelData[row * width * channelCount + col + 1] = 0x0000;
                    intPixelData[row * width * channelCount + col + 2] = 0xffff;
                }
                else
                {
                    intPixelData[row * width * channelCount + col + 0] = 0x0000;
                    intPixelData[row * width * channelCount + col + 1] = 0xffff;
                    intPixelData[row * width * channelCount + col + 2] = 0x0000;
                }
            }
        }
        Buffer.BlockCopy(intPixelData, 0, imgdata, 0, imgdata.Length);

        // compose the BitmapImage
        var image = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, dpiX, dpiY, PixelFormats.Rgb48, null, imgdata, stride);
        BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fn, FileMode.Create))
        {
            encoder.Save(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

Similarly, for jpeg, I used:
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

But the file generated size is wrong and BmpBitmapDecoder show the format is default for bmp and rgb24 for jpg. they are not rgb48. what is wrong?

Comment: The most basic thing that's wrong is that there isn't actually any image file format that supports Rgb48.  So it picks the next best format.  You are wasting time and memory trying it anyway.  These formats were picked back when GDI+ was created with the *assumption* that technology would improve to make those formats useful some day.  That day did not yet come.